# How to plot a satellite ground track onto a map projection in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I'm trying to plot the ground-track of a satellite in a given orbit in Matlab. I already have the data sets that contain the x, y, z position of the satellite as well as the longitude and latitude data. I only have a problem with plotting it.

I already made a scatter3(x, y, z) graph which looks okay but I want to make a 2D projection onto a map in the well-known ground-track style. If I simply do plot(longitude, latitude) the graph will by wierd as you would expect without any projection.

**My data:**

```
[x; y; z; long; lat]
```

All five are arrays containing a few revolutions worth of position data. How do I make an earth-map like 2D - plot where the lines look like sinusoids? I couldn't find anything in Matlab's help section about projections.

Comment: Do you have the MATLAB Mapping Toolbox or are you trying to do this with vanilla MATLAB?

Comment: I think vanilla Matlab. I have a student license. I downloaded some libraries that do something similar but those are overkill for me.

Comment: Wait, now I found the Mapping Toolbox, but I don't know what to actually look for. The projections section didn't really help me.

Comment: [m_map](https://www.google.fr/search?q=m_map+matlab&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS649US649&oq=m_map+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0j69i59l2j0l2.3753j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) toolbox

Answer (score 1):

The best thing I found was using the "worldmap world" function which looks like the following:

```
worldmap world
load coastlines
[latcells, loncells] = polysplit(coastlat, coastlon);
plotm(coastlat, coastlon, 'green')
hold on
plotm(lat, long, 'blue')
```

where lat and long are the vectors containing the position data.